# React.js and Component local vars

Tags: reactjs

Is it appropriate (proper patter), when you need to use a variable local to the component but feel props/state is not appropriate because it does not drive ui, and to pass it in as a prop is ponderous.

So, I am doing something with movement, so my component needs to know the size of the window. So, I just figure to add a var to contain it:

```jsx
var BoxMove = React.createClass({
      displayName: "movable box",

      clientWidth: document.documentElement.clientWidth, // this here

      getDefaultProps: function() {
        // etc..
      }

      render: function() {
         // use the local var
          var move = 0;
          if(this.clientWidth > 1000) {
            move = 100;
          }

         return (// whatever
         )
      }
})
```

Is that an appropriate usage and place to add a variable that doesn't fit into a "state" or "prop"? I only showed one usage, but I will probably be calling to to that var a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be fine, yes. The other way to handle this, if you're using Flux with React, is to put that information into a store. But if this suits your needs, you should be good to go.